# Convert optimised gif to single frames using ImageMagick

Tags: imagemagick, gif

I have some creative Commons gifs I would like to use, but I need them as single frames. However, the gif is optimised, so when I pull it apart via

```
convert the.gif frames/%02d.tga
```

Some of the images are just fragments out of place, and way smaller than the original one.

So is there a way to render the single frames as they're viewed in a viewer?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to extract frames from a GIF file preserving frame dimensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12791505/how-to-extract-frames-from-a-gif-file-preserving-frame-dimensions)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you may want to add a [`-coalesce`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php?#coalesce) option to your command: `convert -coalesce the.gif frames/%02d.tga`

Comment: Upvote for linking to the documentation ... thank you!