# How to extract frames from a GIF file preserving frame dimensions

Tags: imagemagick, gif

I have the following GIF image file:

[image: original gif image]

I want to extract its frames (using PGM output format) using this imagemagick command:

```
convert brocoli.gif out%05d.pgm
```

But each frame has a different size.

How can I extract its frames while preserving the original gif file size?

Comment: MRI of broccoli?

Comment: yes! (lorem ipsum text)

Comment: I have watched this broccoli MRI many times now. Fascinating.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Use the `-coalesce` option:

`convert -coalesce brocoli.gif out%05d.pgm`

Comment: This works great! for who like me is puzzled from this option, the documentation says `Overlay each image in an image sequence according to its -dispose meta-data, to reproduce the look of an animation at each point in the animation sequence`.

Comment: I'll one-up you in terms of necromancy, joe.. @gipi I am not a gif or imagemagick expert, but my understanding of GIF is that it's a sequence of fairly independent images, where each image in the sequence can be a different size. they're layered on top of each other to produce the overall animation. This provides some compression because parts of the image which don't change are not included in each frame.  Per the docs you quoted, `-coalesce` performs the layering of each frame on the whole before exporting.

Answer (score 4):

You can use graphicsmagick:

`gm convert Test.gif +adjoin Test_image%3d.png`

or

`gm convert Test.gif -coalesce +adjoin Test_image%3d.png`.